# Selenium: select Row and then click on Approve and Delete option

Tags: selenium

I created a row  with list of items, every time i fill the list and click on save
[image]

it will create one row.Need to select this row and click on approve then it will get approved. Able to select the row using Click and hold, and navigating to approve options it will clear the row selection.please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Any effort from your side?

Comment: I tried with different combination but not no effect. it is selecting individually one by one but i need to select row(selection should not fade) then go for approve button

Comment: Why are you using clickandhold? How do you do it manually? Click on row to select and then click approve button?

Comment: Provide code and console error.

Comment: Yes , correct i'm exactly doing that.Manually i used to select the Row first then after i'm clicking approve button

Comment: Hi sanjay, i'm not getting any console error, it is successfully executing but it is taking the actions individually but my theme is to select the row after need to approve the selection.